# multiple select statement on one column php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i am trying to retrieve a list of records from my database and table using two criterias and the data has to be combined as one

the first statement which i have written is

```
FROM `transactions` WHERE `Start_Date` = '$_POST[start]' AND `Company` = '$_POST[star]' and Status = ''
```

this statement all the records which has its column as empty,

now i want to also capture  together with this data all columns that have status as successful

```
FROM `transactions` WHERE `Start_Date` = '$_POST[start]' AND `Company` = '$_POST[star]' and Status = 'successful'
```

please how do i combine this, i initially tried this

FROM `transactions` WHERE `Start_Date` = '$_POST[start]' AND `Company` = '$_POST[star]' and Status = '' and (status = 'successful')

i thought it should work but it dosent seem to work, any help please on the correct way

Comment: Just a heads up: By putting `$_POST` variables directly into a SQL query, you're enabling people to run any SQL query their heart desires on your database.

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up, ill mk necessary adjustments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row in your table will be evaluated individually to see if it meets the criteria defined in the `WHERE` clause. Since you need to check for two possible values in the same column, and one row cannot have two different values for the same column, you'll need to use `OR` instead of `AND`.

```
WHERE
    `Start_Date` = '$_POST[start]'
     AND `Company` = '$_POST[star]'
     AND (`Status` = '' OR `Status` = 'successful')
```

The effect of this will be like combining your two queries. You'll get all rows that meet the `Start_date` and `Company` criteria as well as having *either* `Status = ''` *or* `Status = 'successful'`.

Comment: but i need all the records that have status are empty and successful, hw can that not be possible

Comment: @TeeFamakin I edited the answer to try to explain why you need OR. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "IN" operator to achieve this.

FROM 'transactions' 
WHERE 'Start_Date' = '$_POST[start]' AND 'Company' = '$_POST[star]' AND 
Status IN ('','successful')